# IOS Swift- UITabBar custom tabbar leaves empty space on start and end of the bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tabbar

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.tabBar .invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    let tabSize: CGFloat = 80

    var tabFrame: CGRect = self.tabBar.frame;
    tabFrame.size.height = tabSize;
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - tabSize;
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;

    self.tabBar.translucent = false;
    self.tabBar.translucent = true;

}
```

This code is working fine is iPhone5, but in higher screen it leave empty space. Is their any way i can adjust the the selected tab size to make it wide or any other solution.
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: then you must have to write this code with different value for different device .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Do you have any example?

Comment: i dont have example but i have code that you can find which device your application run . so you can arrage the size of your tab bar

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Ya i do have that, but i tried changing value, that also not working.

Comment: check my answer hope its help you.

Comment: you should use constraints for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.view.frame.size.width > 376 {
           // here code for iphone 6 and 7 plus 
}
else if self.view.frame.size.width > 320 && self.view.frame.size.width <= 375 {
     // write code for iphone 6 and 6s and 7
}
else{
       if self.view.frame.size.height <= 232 {
            //write code for iphone 4s 
       }
       else {
           //write code for iphone 5 and 5s

       }
}
```

**Other options :**

```
let tabSize: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width / 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set tabSize like this :

```
let tabSize: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width / 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using autolayout and your tab bar is using trailing and leading constraints to the container view, try setting them as equal width and center horizontally instead.